# Is it possible to extract text from PDF, whose "Page Extraction" is not allowed?

Tags: java, python, itext, pdftotext, pypdf

I am able to extract text from PDF's which doesn't have any security restrictions. I just want to know if it is possible to extract text from PDF which has restrictions

[image]

**UPDATE:**

> Thanks to all for your comments. I appreciate your concern. Please understand the question. I did not ask how to do it. I just want to know if it is possible. I have created a PDF with these restrictions. I do not want my information to be extracted from my document. There are many developers who can achieve any task. I want to know if this task can be done. If this can be done, then I will investigate further to overcome this issue.

Comment: And also could you please specify reason for down voting, if you have one? I will modify the question if it needs to be.Thank you.

Comment: You tagged this question with a lot of tags that are not relevant to your question in its current form.

Comment: What have you tried, what did you expect, what was the actual outcome, what didn't work, where is your code?

Comment: I assume the down vote is due to you apparently attempting to do something explicitly forbidden. If a document has essentially every non-viewing permission denied, then please respect this. If you don't, you won't be in a position to complain if someone else ever hacks into your software or information.

Comment: This isn't a question that is eligible for Stack Overflow. Please delete it. Note: once the question is deleted, the reputation loss due to down votes is undone.

Comment: @Amedee Van Gasse, I have used these tags because, these are the few languages and libraries I used to extract text from my PDF before setting up the restrictions. I am not able to extract the information after adding additional security to my document. I have not tried anything because I do not know if this is possible.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, I cannot delete this post. And I am not here for reputation. I am here to learn and to share my knowledge.

Comment: So you are saying that you have used iText in Python? How have you done that? Always interesting to learn!

Comment: @Amedee Van Gasse, I used PDFBox & IText using Java to extract text from PDF. And also I am aware of a little bit Python. So I used pypdf2 & pdfminer using Python to extract text from PDF. I did not include PDFBox & pdfminer tags because of the limitations. As you know we can include only 5 tags.

Comment: That was very unclear and missing from your original question.

Comment: @Amedee Van Gasse, Yes, I accept that. And that is the reason I requested users to specify a reason instead of just down voting, so that I can modify it accordingly. I would have asked in a different way if I want the code to extract protected PDF's. I would have posted the code I tried to extract the text. And my question would have started with "How to".

Comment: Well I don't know who downvoted, wasn't me. The question was clear enough to be salvagable if additional information were to be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As the OP clarified that he asked the question to know whether his documents with such restrictions are safe from text extraction, and that he does not ask how to do it (in spite of the explicit languages and libraries given in tags), here an answer on the principle option, not a concrete implementation. Thus...*

**Yes, it is possible to extract text from documents with restrictions as long as the document can be read at all and no other means are applied to prevent text extraction.**

The restrictions you show merely are flags that indicate to a PDF processor what the author wants to allow or not to allow a user to do with his document but they are not technical restrictions.

These restrictions can only be applied to encrypted documents, but you surely want these restrictions to work in particular for anyone (other than you) who can open the document for reading, be it by knowing a specific user password or be it by using the empty password.

Cf. the specification ISO 32000 (here from part 2, similarly in part 1 with a focus on PDF viewers):

> If a user attempts to open an encrypted document that has a user password, the PDF reader shall first try to authenticate the encrypted document using the padding string defined in 7.6.4.3, "File encryption key algorithm" (default user password):
>
> - If this authentication attempt is successful, the PDF reader may open, decrypt, render and otherwise provide access to the document.
> - If this authentication attempt fails, the interactive PDF processor should prompt for a password. Correctly supplying either password (owner or user password) should enable the user to gain access to the document.
>
> Whether additional operations shall be allowed on a decrypted document depends on which password (if any) was supplied when the document was opened and on any access restrictions that were specified when the document was created:
>
> - Opening the document with the correct owner password should allow full (owner) access to the document. This unlimited access includes the ability to change the document’s passwords and access permissions.
> - Opening the document with the correct user password (or opening a document with the default password) should allow additional operations to be performed according to the user access permissions specified in the document’s encryption dictionary.
>
> Access permissions shall be specified in the form of flags corresponding to the various operations and the set of operations to which they correspond shall depend on the security handler’s revision number (also stored in the encryption dictionary).
>
> ...
>
> Once the document has been opened and decrypted successfully, a PDF reader technically has access to the entire contents of the document. There is nothing inherent in PDF encryption that enforces the document permissions specified in the encryption dictionary. PDF readers shall respect the intent of the document creator by restricting user access to an encrypted PDF file according to the permissions contained in the file.

*(ISO 32000-2 section 7.6.4 Standard Security Handler)*

Thus, these restrictions only work in cooperating PDF processors, but in particular in case of open source PDF libraries, it is trivial for a programmer to remove any code trying to enforce the restrictions.

Being aware of this, the developers of open source PDF libraries usually don't try to enforce the restrictions at all, or they add some flag to override restriction enforcement to prevent patched copies of the library to circulate.