# How does admin password security work in pdfs?

Tags: security, pdf

This may be a stupid question, but I couldn't find it out on my own.

So when you password protect a pdf you can have a separate "admin" password. I understand that you can set it up so that the password is the decryption key, therefore it's impossible to read the contents without the password. However, I cannot understand how the admin password part works. If I decrypt the contents what's stopping me from copying / modifying the pdf?

The only way I can think of is "frontend security", i.e. pdf viewer apps won't let you do that. But from a technical standpoint if the decrypted data is in my RAM it seems impossible to stop me from doing anything I want with that data.

Can anyone explain or point to a resource explaining it from a technical standpoint. When I try to search for it I get sites explaining it from a user's perspective, not how it's technically achieved.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place for this question. However, there exist other sites in the SE network that may be informative: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68853/how-strong-is-pdf-security-encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain or point to a resource explaining it from a technical standpoint.

You can find a technical explanation in the PDF specification ISO 32000. Section 7.6 explains encryption. Adobe published a free copy of the older (2008) ISO 32000-1 at http://Adobe.com/go/pdfreference

Concerning your question

> If I decrypt the contents what's stopping me from copying / modifying the pdf?

it in particular says:

| ISO 32000-1, end of section 7.6.3.1 |
| --- |
| Once the document has been opened and decrypted successfully, a conforming reader technically has access to the entire contents of the document. There is nothing inherent in PDF encryption that enforces the document permissions specified in the encryption dictionary. Conforming readers shall respect the intent of the document creator by restricting user access to an encrypted PDF file according to the permissions contained in the file. |

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it provides a source, unlike the one I've linked to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this in the future, I found the answer here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227100/pdf-user-password-always-give-access-to-the-owner-password-even-when-encrypted

Yes, the admin / owner password is just "frontend security", i.e. no actual security.

What a joke that such a common format contains what essentially amounts to, as the responder in my link called it, snake oil.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do a RAM walk using hardware access completely bypassing the CPU, then nobody can stop you, indeed.

Protection basically means that in one of the application isolation levels, or rings, you can't actually access protected data without raising access to the new level. for example, if you work in protected mode CPU, without special access token allowing to read protected memory, any attempt to read from the protected memory will lead to exception or even CPU halt or kernel panic, depending of OS type, CPU type and RAM type as well.

Comment: I think I get your point, but it seems weird that a file format would have a special security measure to allow / not allow you to do something based on your OS permission level. We already have file access permissions in the OS. Anyhow, the RAM reading was just a general statement about frontend security. Let me rephrase it. If a pdf viewer can use the password to decrypt the data, what's stopping me from writing a utility that does the same, then copies the decrypted contents without the admin password part and saves it as a new file?