# Why the PDF encrypted by only Owner Password can be decrypted easily?

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF that has only an Owner password (16 characters containing alphanumeric and symbols) set. I am able to open the PDF, but certain functions such as editing and printing are restricted.（like below）
[image: when opened by Adobe Acrobat]
[image]

We can do `Change Settings` by entering correct Owner password.

However, it seems that this PDF can be easily decrypted by some software. For example, [using the Coherent PDF JavaScript API](https://www.coherentpdf.com/manuals.html) as shown below, the PDF can be decrypted even if the password is incorrect:

```
cpdf.decryptPdf(pdf, '');
```

In addition, online tools such as https://smallpdf.com/unlock-pdf can also unlock the Owner password without knowing the password. However, it seems that this cannot be done for the User password. Why is this so? What is the mechanism behind removing the password?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75608150/1729265) ("admin password" = owner password). Concerning *"the PDF can be decrypted even if the password is incorrect"* - but that password is correct! A PDF with "only a owner password" actually also does have a user password: the empty string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `cpdf.decryptPdfOwner` with the blank password, you will see that it fails. Conversely, if you run `cpdf.decryptPdf` with the owner password, it will fail.

The algorithms for decrypting a PDF with the user and owner password are different, but they both yield information allowing a PDF program to decrypt all the objects in a file.

A very common pattern is for a PDF to have a blank user password and a non-blank owner password. Thus, it opens without a password. However, the restrictions on printing etc. are entirely enforced by the PDF reader or processing program. There is nothing stopping Adobe Reader from printing a file marked as "no printing" if it has a blank password - it's just policy.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I totally understood this specification!